# swift4 how to use firebase Crashlytics for nutiple bundle identifier for mutiple identifier IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, swift4, crashlytics

I am using firebase in my project for tracking the random crashes.

Following steps I followed for creating a demo project:

1. Create a project on Firebase console
2. after this then I create three project Dev, Staging, Production sub-projects with their respective bundle identifier and also download their google-info.plist
3. add the link of chunk on AppDlegate Class
4. also install the pod by creating podifle
5. the different Plist is added into a different directory in the project src folder like dev, prod, staging
6. my project is also communicating with the firebase server

   ISSUES: I am not able to get the crash mails and not even on the Crashlytics Dashboard

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDVii.png)

Kindly provide me appropriate solution

Answer (score 0):

Firebaser here - this link describes how to configure a multi-environment setup for both iOS and Android: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects. If this doesn't help you achieve what you're looking for, could you go into some more details why, in order to better understand your use case?